# XSLT 2.0/3.0 : how to refer xslt-template variable (stack/map/arraylist) and do push/pop/peek/add/remove operation on template parameter

Tags: java, xslt, stack, saxon

I have the below code  for using xsl-template as below:

```xml
<xsl:template name="closingRecords">
 
        <xsl:param name="recordStackToBeGeneratedLocal" /> <!-- it is java stack contains list of values which i want to procees it-->

        <xsl:if test="not(stack:empty($recordStackToBeGeneratedLocal))">


                            <xsl:variable name="dummstack"  select="stack:push($recordStackToBeGeneratedLocal, 'helpppppp')"/> --> it does not add 
                             pop   recordStackToBeGenerated : <xsl:value-of select="stack:pop($recordStackToBeGeneratedLocal)"/> --> does not peek the stack .. prints all values
                             pop1   recordStackToBeGenerated : <xsl:value-of select="stack:peek($recordStackToBeGeneratedLocal)"/> --> does not peek the stack .. prints all values
                               recordStackToBeGenerated : <xsl:value-of select="(stack:empty($recordStackToBeGeneratedLocal))"/>  --> false

        </xsl:if>

</xsl:template>
```

Please let me know why the push/pop/peek operation is not doing anything. Let me know if I have to use the template parameter and use a different way.

After any push/pop/peek operation, the variable is not changing the content of the stack. how I can change the value of recordStackToBeGeneratedLocal (push/pop/peek) inside the xslt-template?

Comment: Can you include a link to the API documentation of the Java Stack and show us more context on how you pass in the parameter from Java, which version of Saxon you use, how you declared the prefix `stack`?

Comment: I am using saxonic PE version and imported java collection lib. 
 XALAN jar has snyk vunerabilty so we can not use it furthermore .<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="3.0"
              

                xmlns:stack="java:java.util.Stack"
                xmlns:al="java:java.util.ArrayList"
                xmlns:df="java:java.text.DecimalFormat"
                xmlns:ht="java:java.util.Hashtable"
                extension-element-prefixes="datetime" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xsi:schemaLocation="">

Comment: Consider to edit your question with the details you have tried to put in a comment and also consider to add the Java code setting the parameter and showing us which API you use to set the parameter. Also telling us the exact Saxon version also helps.

Comment: Thanks . Java code does not have anything for stack related and all stack related operation is done in xslt as below  <xsl:variable name="recordStackToBeGeneratedLocal" select="stack:new()"/> <xsl:variable name="dummstack"  select="stack:push($recordStack, '002')"/> ..When I pass this reference to xslt-template then I am not able to do any push/peek/pop operation(means recordStackToBeGeneratedLocal kind of immutable even if copied value into local variable it is not allowing push/pop/peek)

Comment: As said before, consider to edit your question and provide all necessary details in there in a more readable and well-formatted way then stuffing it into comments.

Comment: Hi Martin, After any push/pop/peek operation the variable is not changing the content of stack. how I can change the value of recordStackToBeGeneratedLocal (push/pop/peek)?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for calling Java methods from Saxon can be found at https://www.saxonica.com/documentation11/index.html#!extensibility/extension-functions-J/reflexive-functions

Use of extension functions with side-effects (such as `stack:push`) is generally discouraged, though you can get away with it if you are very careful.

In particular, invoking such a function within `xsl:variable` is usually a mistake, because Saxon does lazy evaluation of variables, which means the order of evaluation is not as written (and variables that are never referenced will never be evaluated at all). You can get better control over order of evaluation by using the `saxon:do` instruction, but even there you need care: for example don't use it within a variable or function body.

For data structures such as stacks, arrays, maps, and lists, XSLT 3.0 provides all the data types you need and there's no need to call out to Java for this functionality.

Comment: Thanks Michael. As you suggested, I replaced java: stack via xslt:array and remove all java dependencies.  We have main template which is calling other template with many xsl:choose and inside the when/othewise case we are updating(add/remove item) array object but due to this changed/updated array object is not getting passed tp subsequence template/further code due to out-of-scope(after update of the object)..  So it there way I can create a global array where I can reference for all templated and sub-flows.

Comment: It's not constructive to pursue this both on StackOverflow and on other channels. For my part, I'm much happier doing it on a public forum where others can chip in their ideas; but it also falls rather outside the simple question/answer format of StackOverflow, which doesn't encourage asking supplementary questions as a comment on a previous answer....

Comment: I think the basic problem is not with the mechanics of calling extension functions, it's that you're using extension functions to write procedural code that relies on mutable variables; and when you've got code that's written like that, redesigning it into declarative logic can be a tough project.